# "Manipulate only center" when scaling in Blender 2.9? Where did it go?

Tags: modeling, scale

I have looked everywhere and all the information is outdated to version 2.8. There used to be an option in the "options" drop down that said "Manipulate centers only" or "affect location only". Anybody know where this feature went? Because it is a pretty useful feature and I can't for the life of me figure out where it went off to.

Edit: This got flagged as being a possible duplicate question of another question, but that other question was for 2.8 NOT 2.9. I am looking for the feature in 2.9
[image]

This image above is what I see when I click the options drop down menu

Comment: No, I am looking for the feature in Blender 2.9 not 2.8

Comment: Hello @Blith :). The linked solution works the same for Blender 2.9. It's by no means outdated :).

Comment: Hey @JachymMichal , I checked the linked solution for 2.8, and the option is literally not where that post says it is though... I click on the options drop down, and I do not have the "Affect locations" button.  edited my post with a picture of what I see when I hit the options drop down menu

Comment: Nothing has changed. You need to be in **Object Mode**, not in edit mode to access those tools. https://i.stack.imgur.com/yyBNc.gif

Comment: @susu Thanks, I did not know the feature could only be used in Object Mode. So you can't use the feature for just faces or edges at all?? For example, I would like to splay legs of a table out in separate directions, but just the bottom face of the leg, so that the legs become diagonal

Comment: You can only manipulate the origin of the mesh in object mode. To manipulate geometry in edit mode using custom axis or pivot points use the **Transform Pivot Point** options.